# How to get custom object variable into new activity?

Tags: java, android

Ok so I want imageviews on each individual activity to be set based on the my object stretches that is initialized in the main activity. I can't set it to static because `getString`, `getResources`, and this cannot be used from a static context.

Here is the relevant part of the mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static int pos = 0, time = 60;
    public static Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

    final stretch[] stretches = new stretch[]{new stretch(this, 
            ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1, null),
                    true, getString(R.string.SEdescription)),
                    new stretch(this, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.pic2, null),
                            true, getString(R.string.USSdescription)),
                    new stretch(this, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.pic2, null),
                            true, getString(R.string.RHCdescription)),
                    new stretch(this, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.pic2, null),
                            true, getString(R.string.FSdescription)),
                    new stretch(this, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.pic2, null),
                            true, getString(R.string.SPdescription)),
                    new stretch(this, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.pic2, null),
                            true, getString(R.string.KLdescription)),
                    new stretch(this, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.pic2, null),
                            true, getString(R.string.BFdescription)),
                    new stretch(this, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.pic2, null),
                            true, getString(R.string.BBdescription)),
                    new stretch(this, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), 
            R.drawable.pic2, null),
                            true, getString(R.string.LTdescription))
    };
```

How can I get this array to be accessible in other activities so I can do things like `stretch[1].getImage();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a class for your custom object and I have made something from your code.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class stretch implements Parcelable {

    private Context myContext;
    private Drawable myDrawable;
    private boolean myBoolean;
    private String myString;

    public final static Parcelable.Creator<stretch> CREATOR = new Creator<stretch>() {
        @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
        public stretch createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new stretch(in);
        }

        public stretch[] newArray(int size) {
            return (new stretch[size]);
        }
    };

    protected stretch(Parcel in) {
        this.myContext = ((Context) in.readValue((Context.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.myDrawable = ((Drawable) in.readValue((Drawable.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.myBoolean = ((boolean) in.readValue((boolean.class.getClassLoader())));
        this.myString = ((String) in.readValue((String.class.getClassLoader())));
    }
    public stretch(Context myContext, Drawable myDrawable, boolean myBoolean, String object) {
        this.myContext = myContext;
        this.myDrawable = myDrawable;
        this.myBoolean = myBoolean;
        this.myString = object;
    }

    public Context getMyContext() {
        return myContext;
    }

    public void setMyContext(Context myContext) {
        this.myContext = myContext;
    }

    public Drawable getMyDrawable() {
        return myDrawable;
    }

    public void setMyDrawable(Drawable myDrawable) {
        this.myDrawable = myDrawable;
    }

    public boolean isMyBoolean() {
        return myBoolean;
    }

    public void setMyBoolean(boolean myBoolean) {
        this.myBoolean = myBoolean;
    }

    public String getMyString() {
        return myString;
    }

    public void setMyString(String myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeValue(myContext);
        dest.writeValue(myDrawable);
        dest.writeValue(myBoolean);
        dest.writeValue(myString);
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

In your activity change,

> final stretch[] stretches

to

```
ArrayList<stretch> stretches = new ArrayList();
```

and then add items using

```
stretches.add(new stretch(this, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.pic1, null), true, getString(R.string.SEdescription)))
stretches.add(new stretch(this, ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.pic2, null), true, getString(R.string.USSdescription)))
//likewise add all other items
```

And to pass this to an activity,

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, NextActivity.class)
        .putParcelableArrayListExtra("stretches", stretches));
```

To obtain your array in your `NextActivity`,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ArrayList<stretch> stretchList = getIntent().getParcelableArrayListExtra("stretches");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some methods you can try

**1. Create class**

```
public class SomeClassYouWant implements Parcelable {
@DrawableRes
int drawableIconOrImage;
Object idkWhyYourPassNull;
@StringRes
int stringYouWant;

protected SomeClassYouWant(Parcel in) {
    drawableIconOrImage = in.readInt();
    stringYouWant = in.readInt();
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeInt(drawableIconOrImage);
    dest.writeInt(stringYouWant);
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

public static final Creator<SomeClassYouWant> CREATOR = new Creator<SomeClassYouWant>() {
    @Override
    public SomeClassYouWant createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new SomeClassYouWant(in);
    }

    @Override
    public SomeClassYouWant[] newArray(int size) {
        return new SomeClassYouWant[size];
    }
};
```

}

```
List<SomeClassYouWant> mList= new ArrayList<>();
```

Then Pass through the activities

```
startActivity(new Intent(context, SomeActivity.class)
            .putParcelableArrayListExtra("list", mList));
```

**2. Create a global**

Create variable in `Application` class and use `Getters` and `Setters` for accessing, Your object will be stays as long as your application running but this method is not recommended